# Как скопировать массив в список

Tags: c#, динамические-массивы, списки

Есть массив

```
string[][][] paralels = { чтото-там };
```

Нужно скопировать его в список

```
List<List<string>> paralels_copy = paralels[ключ];
```

Как провернуть такой трюк?

Comment: Никак, исходный массив "трехмерный", а список "двухмерный". Или вы неправильно описали задачу

Comment: разве это правильное определение трехмерного массива, я думаю что это более приемлемый вариант string[,,] paralels = new string[,,]{};

Comment: @АндрейNOP Я указал первый ключ значит массив стал двумерным.

Comment: @Yaroslav Если это поможет решению тогда можно попробовать изменить структуру

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
List<List<string>> paralels_copy = paralels[0].Select(a => a.ToList()).ToList();
```